# symfony2 first doctrine query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying make my first query on symfony2 so the question will be maybe stupid.

I have my table with users and table with (friends) requests. In requests table i store

id,nick(id),odobera(another user Id- who i follow),time

And the nick property looks:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="Requests")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nick", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

And now i want rebuild my old functional query to the new symfony one:

```
    $select_all=mysql_query("SELECT re.*,tb.rank,tb.profile_picture_ultra_small,tb.country,tb.typ_hraca,tb.rank 
                            FROM requests as re
                            INNER JOIN tb_users as tb
                            ON re.nick=tb.nick
                            WHERE re.odobera='$nick' AND re.nick<>'$nick' ORDER BY re.id DESC LIMIT 50");
```

I started just simply:

```
public function getMyFollowers($my_id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('mf')
               ->select('mf')
               ->where('mf.odobera = :my_id')
               ->addOrderBy('mf.time','DESC')
               ->setParameter('my_id', $my_id)
               ->setMaxResults(50);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

I dont have there the inner join for selecting profile_picture of user who follow me + my result looks weird when i dump it now: (as you can see there is no ID (nick) of the user who follow me)

```
"Proxies\__CG__\TB\UserBundle\Entity\User" ["odobera"]=> int(25) ["time"]=> int(1359128544) ["viewed"]=> bool(true) } [6]=> object(stdClass)#624 (6) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(33) "TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests" ["id"]=> int(57443) ["nick"]=> string(40) "Proxies\__CG__\TB\UserBundle\Entity\User" ["odobera"]=> int(25) ["time"]=> int(1359124714) ["viewed"]=> bool(true) } [7]=> object(stdClass)#625 (6) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(33) "TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests" ["id"]=> int(57013) ["nick"]=> string(40) "Proxies\__CG__\TB\UserBundle\Entity\User" ["odobera"]=> int(25) ["time"]=> int(1359047459) ["viewed"]=> bool(true) } [8]=> object(stdClass)#626 (6) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(33) "TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests" ["id"]=> int(56766) ["nick"]=> string(40)
```

Any ideas please? :P Thx!

i tried add this to my entity as you said but changed the names but i think it doesn't make sence at all and my query was loading 9s in one time and withdrawed just one user + i cant load the page now...
USERS:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests", mappedBy="following")
 *
 **/
private $followers;
```

REQUESTS:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="followers")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nick", referencedColumnName="id")
**/
```

private $following;

But ... it doesn't make sence..

Answer (score 1):

You can define a Repository for user class adding the annotation to User class.

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\YourBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
```

And inside the repository you will have:

```
public function getFollowers($id)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('user')
        ->from('YourBundle:User', 'user')
        ->leftJoin('user.requests', 'friends')
        ->where('friends.odobera = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->orderBy('friends.time', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(50);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Check this [Custom Repositories](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories)

On your controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->getFollowers($id);
```

Mapping info example

On Users

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Followers", mappedBy="following")
 *
 **/
private $followers;
```

On Followers (the table were you defined the followers)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="followers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $following;
```

Comment: Yes i have it in my repository generated by bundle :) Hm... and this query how should i use ?         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        
        $myFollowers = $em->getRepository('RequestsBundle:Requests')->getMyFollowers('25');

Comment: That's it ;) I added to the answer.

Comment: Okay thx man, but why getRepository User? And not friends? I am going to try it.

Comment: The query I defined will get up to 50 users that are following you, it will return an array of Users objects.

Comment: Hm... but i am confused a little be ... Why you used the getFollowers on User entity? + the friends.odobera was throwing an error to me so i delete it to                $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('mf')
                ->select('user')
                ->from('UserBundle:User', 'user')
                ->leftJoin('requests', 'requests')
                ->where('requests.odobera = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->orderBy('requests.time', 'DESC')
                ->setMaxResults(50); but now i have this error: Class 'requests' is not defined.

Comment: on the left side of the join you need to specify the entity and the field like user.requests and on the right the other entity to do the join. Exactly what you want?

Comment: How i said withdrawn people who follow me... as i describe in old query. Exactly like that. But in my UserBundle:User Entity i dont have any requests field. And in Requests class also i dont have any extra fields just that what i descibet up. I read somewhere about ArrayCollection but... is that this case? :P

Comment: If you define a bidirectional M:N relation between User and Friend this query should work http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: You can see in my post... i have defined the ManyToOne relationship and no extra fields. Should i somehow modify my code now? i am really noob so if i am missing something please tell me. Thx :)

Comment: Add Entities code, because according to your mapping annotation you have a requests field on Users due to this inversedBy="Requests"

Comment: i added it there just...  dont know why.. i am still getting some error and cant find solution ah it makes my crazy. What exactly should i add to User Entity please?

Comment: I added an example of how should looks both entities, read the documentation carefully, is not to complicated.